# Objective-C: Using self.navigationController with a Custom UINavigationController

Tags: properties, uinavigationcontroller, custom-component

I have created a custom navigation controller which I call `CatalogueNavigationController`. This `CatalogueNavigationController` has a property called `currentLevel` which is of type `int`.

On one of my view controllers that are presented within this navigation controller, I would like to get the `CatalogueNavigationController`'s `currentLevel` value. However, when I try to reference it with `self.navigationController.currentLevel`, I'm faced with an error that suggests that currentLevel isn't a property of `UINavigationController` - I know, it's part of `CatalogueNavigationController`.

CatalogueNavigationController

```
// .h
@interface CatalogueNavigationController : UINavigationController
@property int currentLevel;

// .m
@implementation CatalogueNavigationController
@synthesize currentLevel;
```

Initialising View Controller

```
CatalogueBrowser *catalogue = [[CatalogueBrowser alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped andQuery:nil];
CatalogueNavigationController *navigation = [[CatalogueNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:catalogue];
navigation.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:navigation animated:YES];
```

CatalogueBrowser View Controller

```
NSLog(@"%i",self.navigationController.currentLevel); //ERROR: Property 'currentLevel' not found on object of type 'UINavigationController *'
```

The currentLevel variable is decremented when a viewController is popped and incremented when a viewController is pushed, to allow me to keep track of 'how deep' into the navigation the user is. So I need to return it's current state.

I could use Notifications to marry a variable on my view controller and on the CatalogueNavigationController, but surely there's a more elegant solution?

How can I reference self.navigationController to return the value of `currentLevel`, but have it refer to the `CatalogueNavigationController` and not UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution, is to test if the navigationController is of the type you want, here explained: [In Objective-C, how do I test the object type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144629/in-objective-c-how-do-i-test-the-object-type). And if it is true you cast it to your object and then check the value you want.

Info in casting objects: [ios custom NSObject casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171072/ios-custom-nsobject-casting).

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Cheers for this, but casting in this way will always retrieve the initialised version, not the current instance. Within my CatalogueNavigationController, I increment/decrement currentLevel, which NSLog outputs correctly, with this method, it always returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same situation. I think the solution is this:

```
CatalogueNavigationController *navController = (CatalogueNavigationController *)self.navigationcontroller;

NSLog(@"%i", navController.currentLevel);
```